# How to fix the ERROR Unrecognized arguments: –async-trace when running apppium

Tags: appium, appium-android

**ENVIRONMENT**:

Windows 11

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> appium --version
2.2.1
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm --version
10.2.0
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> java -version
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> sdkmanager --version
4.0.1
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 34.0.5-10900879
Installed as C:\Users\Gauthier\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe
Running on Windows 10.0.22621
```

==========================================

**PROBLEM**:

When I run appium, I get this error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> appium --log appium.log --log-level error:debug --debug-log-spacing --async-trace

[ERROR] Unrecognized arguments: --async-trace
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I get the answer from official Appium team.
With the new version of Appium 2, I need to put :

```
--long-stacktrace
```

instead of

```
--async-trace
```